# Create annotation to perform common action and return result

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I have a Spring REST controller with two endpoints that return a `Foo` and a `Bar` through their corresponding `FooManager.handleFoo` and `BarManager.handleBar` that contains the request handlers:

`/MyService/foo`

`/MyService/bar`

To be able to retrieve the correct `Foo` and `Bar` I need access to a `GroupId` for the calling user. The incoming request will contain the `UserId`. The `UserId` can then be used to make a back-end REST call to another service `/OtherService/baz/{UserId}` and the `OtherService` will return a `GroupId` for the given `UserId`.

Now I would like to "hide" the fetching of the `GroupId` since I need to feetch it for all resources that I return from my service. Preferrably I would like a small annotation that triggers the code that fetches the `GroupId` and that also returns a result. Something like:

```
class FooManager {

  @RequireGroupId
  public Foo handleFoo(GroupId groupId) { ... }

}
```

Thus far I have had a look at [Annotation Processing 101](http://hannesdorfmann.com/annotation-processing/annotationprocessing101), [Spring custom annotations](http://techo-ecco.com/blog/spring-custom-annotations/) and [Custom validation annotation in Spring](http://dolszewski.com/spring/custom-validation-annotation-in-spring/) but none of the articles seem to return a value nor make a network call if that makes any difference.

So:

1. How can I implement such an annotation and processor if possible?
2. If not, how can I effectively make the request to `OtherService` as transparent as possible?

Comment: Have you considered writing a Before Aspect for your controllers where you can do this fetching GroupId by UserdId code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotation is just a marker to do something with this. The logic should check whether method has annotation and apply some code in this case

I would recommend to use Aspects

Check 
https://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-aop-aspectj-annotation-example/ and http://www.journaldev.com/2583/spring-aop-example-tutorial-aspect-advice-pointcut-joinpoint-annotations

```
@Aspect
public class GroupIdRetrieverAspect {

    @Before("execution(* com.your.package.*)")
    public void logBefore(JoinPoint joinPoint) {

        System.out.println("logBefore() is running!");
        //use joinPoint to get called class/method
        //check whether called method has your annotation and retrieve the id
    }

}
```